# customized jquery framework

Tags: jquery

I need some functionality (selectors, some show/hide functions and few more unilities[`$.each()` for example]), in a device with a **very** limited bandwidth and storage.
So, is there a way to build a customized jquery FW?

thanks

Comment: You can use JavaScript for these.

Comment: Well, just take what you need. For example, jQuery selector use [shizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) that you can load. Some jQuery function such as `each` are pretty easy to make from scratch. For more complicated things, there is always a library that can do it better and sometime smaller. Ex : `greensock` for animation, `bluebird` for promise... JQuery is great because it works all together out of the box, but there is always alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create custom builds of jQuery at http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/

You can choose the version of jQuery you want it to be, the elements you require and it lets you know the size of the file you're creating.

I've also noticed that on the jQuery GitHub page, [there's a section on modules](https://github.com/jquery/jquery#modules) explaining what each bit does and explaining how to exclude the things you don't need.